# Windows Authentication is not working in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, windows-authentication

We have a situation where a web application within an intranet requires windows authentication. This way employees of the company can login to their desktops and have automatic access to the web application and also be identified automatically without having to login because Windowns Authentication takes care of that.

The problem is that we've added a Flex module to the web application.  The web application comes up fine and authenticates the user can then navigate to the page where we have the Flex application.  Which loads fine.  The problem is that the Flex application also needs to communicate with the same server about this user but this communication is not working and is prompting the user for a password.  Even if the correct user/pass is entered it fails and the Flex application can't talk to the server which requires Windows authentication.

Our expectations was the since the IE browser housing the flex application was already authenticated that all communication from the Flex app would also carry with it the necessary information to enable it to access the server without authentication. Not sure why this is not working.  Any help is much appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

The way I've handled this in the past is to create an assembly that would go in your Intranet's bin folder that passes the logged in user's information back to the Flex application. There's no need to re-authenticate since they're already logged in to the domain.

Then you can make a call to that assembly using [FluorineFX](http://www.fluorinefx.com/) ([documentation](http://www.fluorinefx.com/docs/fluorine/index.html)) which lets Flex communicate with .NET. (For what it's worth, I also use the [Mate framework](http://mate.asfusion.com/).) Your assembly gets called and the logged in user's information is communicated back to Flex.

Typically I make this call and validate there's a logged in user before starting the rest of the application. This way in case someone tries to grab the swf and use it outside the domain, it won't work.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I understand what you are suggesting and how to let Flex know who the user is.  My problem is that the Flex app still needs to make calls back to the server to get other data.  The server is requiring authentication and the HTTP calls from Flex do not have the necessary data to be authenticated and fail. That's my main problem.  Is one option to have all calls to that server go through FlourineFX instead of directly from Flex?

Comment: FlourineFX and WebORB.net are the same thing, FlourineFX is an open source version and would suit your needs.  You might actually want to think about things for a second before you go around downvoting people....

Comment: @Saviz, That's how I've done it in the past. Any data that goes in or out of my Flex app goes through FluorineFX and consumes some assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Use WebORB, if your using .Net and Flex together save yourself a mountain of time and headaches and let WebORB bind the two pieces together.  It handles Windows path through authentication for you.   Their community edition is free and should suit your needs.

Comment: Jason thank you for your comment.  I understand how WebORB can tell me who the user is.  But how does that solve my problem of specific HTTP requests that I have for the server that requires authentication.  Are you suggesting that WebORB would act as a proxy for all those other calls?

Comment: Did you even bother looking? http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-net/features/weborb-security.html and http://www.themidnightcoders.com/fileadmin/docs/dotnet/v4/guide/index.html?authentication.htm   It allows Flex and .Net to use the same authentication model, is flexible and completely modifiable.  We have used it at the highest level of enterprise sites quite successfully.

Comment: I didn't down vote you.  I don't even have enough reputation to do it.  Someone else must have done that.  I really appreciate your time and your advice and will look into what you are suggesting.

Comment: It's a shame WebORB isn't Java-centric. If I was using .NET on the server, I'd just be using Silverlight for the client. Flex makes more sense paired with Java IMO...

Comment: WebORB has .net, java, and php versions of the server side and allows just about everything from silverlight, flex, flash, javascript, and world + dog to connect to it seemlessly.  Also flourineFX is very similar in design but it opensource.